# Generating an auto incrementing number in rails

Tags: html, css

I am very new to rails and was wondering if someone might be able to help me.

I need to generate and save an auto incrementing number for an invoicing. Ive already created the field 'invoicenum:integer' in my billing_history table.

I was wondering how I can do this from the controller ? This is the entry point where I was wanting to put it. Im not sure how I would write the function to create this incrementing number... Do i write it inside this function or do i create another function outside of this and just call it ?

```
  transaction.company.billing_history.create!(
    reference: transaction.description,
    amount: transaction.amount,
    plan: transaction.plan,
    status: 'success',
    invoicenum: 
  )
```

Comment: Doesn't it disappear already? https://imgur.com/a/D74IZbt

Answer (score 1):

it's more preferable to make your controller slim so for a code like this its better to be on the model

lets say you have
`BillingHistory.rb`

you could set a [callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to generate the invoice number like this

```
class BillingHistory < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :generate_invoice_number
  
  private
    def generate_invoice_number
      # logic for generating invoice number
      # adjust accordingly to your needs
      self.invoicenum = BillingHistory.maximum(:invoicenum).next
    end
end
```

this will assign the value of `BillingHistory.invoicenum` before validated